# react-native-video-controls, audio is not working

Tags: react-native

Running

```
react-native-cli: 0.1.10
react-native: 0.42.0
```

Emulator

```
iPhone 6
```

Device

```
iPhone 7 Plus 10.2.1
iPhone 6
```

Package JSON File

```
"dependencies": {
"axios": "^0.15.3",
"native-base": "^2.0.13",
"react": "15.4.2",
"react-native": "^0.42.0",
"react-native-elements": "^0.10.0",
"react-native-image-slider": "^1.1.5",
"react-native-material-buttons": "^0.2.0",
"react-native-md-textinput": "^2.0.4",
"react-native-video": "^1.0.0",
"react-native-video-controls": "^1.1.1"
},
```

Code Below

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import {
AppRegistry,
StyleSheet,
Text,
View,
StatusBar,
KeyboardAvoidingView,
TabBarIOS,
Image
} from 'react-native';
import { Container, Content, Card, CardItem, Tabs, Tab, Left, Body,Thumbnail,Footer, FooterTab, Button, Icon } from 'native-base';

import VideoPlayer from 'react-native-video-controls';
export default class Test extends Component {

render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.ViewContainer}>
      <VideoPlayer
        source={{ uri: 'https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4' }}
        navigator={ this.props.navigator }
        />
      </View>
    );
}
}
```